# Large bulge inside Beko fridge which is freezing food

Tags: refrigerator, freezing

Hello our Beko LSG1545W fridge has been freezing itself and our food.

We work away for a week at a time sometimes. We came home and our food was frozen even, things on the top shelf. We turned it right down to 1 or 2 and after another week it was still frozen and froze over the back wall also.

I was looking how to change the temperature pcb etc which doesn’t look too hard and couldn’t see how to get the temperature dial and light assembly off. There doesn’t appear to be any screws or clips. I didn’t want to break it by forcing it. Is this model serviceable at all?

But now I have noticed that the inside back wall has a large bulge. You can see where the shelves touch the wall in the centre. It has moved out about 20mm. The bulge maybe feels like air or gas it is quite firm to the touch. You have to push it quite a bit for it to move. Like if you were pushing against a pumped up bicycle tyre. The bulge covers three quarters of the back wall, right from near the top and you can see where it stops where the shadow is in between the two shelves above the wine rack.

I am currently leaving on level 2 out of 5 for 24 hours to see if it freezes some water. Which might imply the temperature pcb is faulty but that was before I noticed the bulge.

I was hoping I could repair myself but now not sure if the bulge could be a gas leak and so would need to get a repair man out which could easily creep up the cost or if it’s just better to by a new one which is about £309

I have cleaned the cooling coils at the outside of the fridge. They were not particularly dirty. I have also checked the seal and it is all good.

What do you guys think could be the cause and the best way forward.

Thanks very much in advance.
[image]

Comment: My first guess would be you have ice buildup back there.  No way to know without disassembly.  It's definitely not gas—nothing in a fridge is air tight except the refrigerant cycle system.

Comment: Usual approach (which is of course difficult if you don't have access to another fridge) is to defrost for 24-48 hours so as to clear any ice blockage.

Comment: When you that it out check there is probably a fan that has failed.

Comment: @Huesmann I should have said it was left off all this week. After turning it on a few hours ago the bulge has now totally disappeared. So it won’t have been ice making the bulge, is that what you meant or did you mean a blockage?

Comment: @Gil I should have said it was left off all this week. After turning it on a few hours ago the bulge has now totally disappeared. I don’t see where a fan would be? Now it’s turned back on as far as I can tell it sounds normal.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I should have said it was left off all this week. After turning it on a few hours ago the bulge inside has now totally disappeared. If it was an ice blockage then that could have cleared it after being off so long, but would it being turned off cause the inside to bulge out.

Comment: Did you observe any puddling at the bottom of the fridge or below it when you had it off?